# Is there R code for anderson darling test for a loglogistic distribution?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I want to test data whether they come from a loglogistic distribution , using Anderson Darling test

I have tried ad.test() using various libraries but I get no result.

Comment: Try the "cmstatr" package https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/cmstatr/html/anderson_darling.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Suggest a Google search: CRAN anderson darling loglogistic. This question is off-topic because it is seeking advice obout software selection.

Comment: A further reason that this question should not be answered is that any regression method that assumes a loglogistic distribution is measuring the **residuals** and not the data itself, so checking for a particular distributional fit on the data might only be informative to the NULL model but not subsequent models.